# Add/Edit text in div class Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, html, selenium

I would like to change the text in a div class, here I would like to change **text**.

```
<div class="selectLabel-2ltwlE" style="flex: 1 1 auto;">text</div>
```

I have already tried this:

```
edit_text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app-mount"]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div')

edit_text.send_keys("Hello")
```

but it didn't work

Thank you, have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the text *you see* with javascript:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].textContent='hello world'", edit_text)
```

This allows you to update the text for whatever your reason is... As a demo, this is your post on this page with a change:

[image: YourNewText]

However, this is only very temporary. This is only in your current session so when you refresh the page or navigate away the change is lost.

Comment: Thank you yes that's exactly what I wanted, thank you very much!